# Union two tables within a single column first category MSYQL

Tags: mysql, union

[image: Example]

Friends and search for information and found help, want to create a query to group two tables in one column and create a separation between shits group, example.

Tale 1 Variants

```
id id_category name
1     101      red
2     101      blue
3     101      green
4     102      dog
5     102      cat
```

Table 2 Category

```
id   name 
101  colors
102  animals
```

Mysql result query

One column:

```
colors "Category name"
red
blue
green
dog
cat
<<<"newline"
animals "Category name"
dog
cat
```

Comment: Why do you have `dog` and `cat` under `colors`?

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could downvote twice.

Comment: @juergend Classic :-)

Comment: Write a query that gets all the colors and a query that gets all the animals. Then combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: If I want to group the results by category cons variants within the same column,

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one column, select just one column...

```
SELECT name from table1
UNION
SELECT "\n"
UNION
SELECT name from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` to combine all results into a single resultset:

```
select `name` as categoryname from table1
union all
select null --this is the "newline"
union all
select `name` from table2
```

Although, I would rather add the new line thing in the application code when you format the results.

Comment: Thanks but in the front row I want to place the title of the name of the category and its variants under the title, a line break and the name of the next category with its variants below.

Comment: Then you need to separate select statements to the union where you select whatever text you want similarly to the `select null` query.

Comment: as I can group the results by category? and that variants under your category display? Thank

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your last question.

Answer (score 0):

This query will do it for the data you've shown.

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, ' Category') AS heading
FROM category
WHERE id = 101
UNION ALL
SELECT name
FROM variants
WHERE id = 101
UNION ALL
SELECT '' -- blank line
SELECT CONCAT(name, ' Category') AS heading
FROM category
WHERE id = 102
UNION ALL
SELECT name
FROM variants
WHERE id = 102
```

If you want to be able to do it for all categories, without hard-coding the IDs, you'll need to write dynamic SQL, or do it in a client programming language. It's not possible with normal SQL.